# Create shape with animation by canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want create shape with canvas similar this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/vkoori123/9sj2kbyt/). 
1- but I want to make another pic with (nudes) dots instead of circle. I know that i have to change the prepare points but changing the pic in this way is very difficult. Is there any easier way? For example wanna make the nudes like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vkoori123/sh6sd5ws/) design.
2- Also i wanna remove the nudes waves. How can i do this?
I wondering if u help me this.

```
vkoori123
```

Answer (score 0):

I remove vibration with this change

```
mouse: { x: -1000, y: -1000, down: true, move: true },
```

and

```
mouseOut: function(event) {
    Nodes.mouse.x = -1000;
    Nodes.mouse.y = -1000;
    Nodes.mouse.down = true;
    Nodes.mouse.move = true;
}
```

now I need just change circle to other photo with another solution (not use preparePoints)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SVG Editor with JavaScript](http://snapsvg.io/)
You will get many more possibilities as per requirement

[Some Demo](http://snapsvg.io/demos/)